# Python Django, Pandas: ForeignKey, his attributes and calculation

Tags: python, django, dataframe, calculation

Good day,

is there any solution to access the attributes of a ForeignKey inside my models.py and also to calculate inside a dataframe?

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.Integerfield(default=0)

class Amounts(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.Integerfield(default=0)
```

Let's say the existing objects are looking something like this:

```
id   |   name   |   price

1    |   name_a |   2
2    |   name_b |   4
3    |   name_c |   8
```

Now I got a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
id | object | amount

1  | name_a | 12
2  | name_b | 7
3  | name_c | 19
```

Is it possible to get the other attributes of the (via foreignkey) connected data and also to calculate inside the dataframe(in this case: price x amount)?

Possible result:

```
id   |   object   |   amount   |   price   |   calc

1    |   name_a   |   12       |   2       |   24
2    |   name_b   |   7        |   4       |   28
3    |   name_c   |   19       |   8       |   152
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So Do you want to calculate it in Dataframe or Queryset itself? I mean Do you preparing those two Dataframes for Merging table and doing calc operation?

Comment: If it's possible, I want to calculate inside the dataframe!

Comment: So basically you want to merge and calculate values from two Dataframes. Right?

Comment: If that's the solution for my problem: yes! Originally I wanted to know, wether I could access the data behind the "ForeignKey"-Connection. For example the price inside my "Object"-Model in the second dataframe. As you can see, I'm refering to it from my "Amounts"-Model. Thanks and I'm hoping my explanation makes some sence for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you

Suppose you are having two Dataframes
i.e df1 and df2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["item1",10],["item2",5], ["item3",6]], columns=["item","price"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["item1",1],["item2",3]], columns=["item","amount"])
```

Which consists of the following data

**df1**

```
      price
item        
item1     10
item2      5
item3      6
```

**df2**

```
       amount
item         
item1       1
item2       3
```

You can join two data frames by index by using `.join` in pandas as below. Please note that `item` is index

```
merged_df = df1.join(df2)
```

`merged_df` looks like

```
       price  amount
item                
item1     10     1.0
item2      5     3.0
item3      6     NaN
```

Now apply your calculation as below. It will do multiplication between column *price* and *amount* and stores it in *calc* column

```
merged_df = merged_df["price"] * merged_df["amount"]
```

Then `merged_df` will be

```
       price  amount  calc
item                      
item1     10     1.0  10.0
item2      5     3.0  15.0
item3      6     NaN   NaN
```

You can find more information from [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

I hope this will solve your problem